# How to manage the OpenAM Log-in page session time-out?

Tags: openam

My manager feels strange about the session time-out on the log-in page.

I tried to persuade her understand the feature, but failed.

Ultimately she think it's a bug.

As I know, the default time-out value is 120(s) on the xml file(JDBC.xml we used).

And code default value is 60.

After I changed the value to 5 sec on the file,

I could check it's affected.

But I changed the value to 7200 on the file,

It's not affected, maybe 120(or 60) default value is applied.

How can I lengthen the time-out value?

or Can I eliminate the log-in page session time-out?

Answer (score 0):

To extend the OpenAM Session timeout, do the following:

```
[openam953]$ cd /home/openam953/opt3/tomcat/webapps/openam953/config/auth/default_en
[openam953]$ vi DataStore.xml
```

Under the ModuleProperties tag, set the timeout property in the Callbacks tag to the number of seconds you want.

You can find more information [here](http://azlabs.blogspot.fr/2011/08/openssoopenam-session-timeout-for-login.html)

Another solution is to refresh the page before the timeout with Javascript when the page is idle, this is better since you don't need to extend the session time-out, you could risk running out of resources on your
OpenAM Host.